# Задача построения VLAN топологии Cisco

Tags: сеть, cisco, vlan, cisco-packet-tracer

[image: Топология]

Дана следующая топология, задача настроить VLAN сеть обозначенную соответствующим цветом, изначальная сеть 192.168.14.0. Главный вопрос для меня можно ли это сделать только с тремя VLSM подсетями?

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду ? 14.0/24 дели себе не хочу...

Answer (score 1):

Как тут правильно сказали, вопрос в том, какую маску вы используете.
Скорее всего дефолт для класса C - /24, то делите на сети равного размера.
Красный цвет - vlan2 192.168.14.0/26, голубой vlan3 192.168.14.64/26, зеленый vlan4 192.168.14.128/26
Касаемо настроек железок - это уже другой вопрос.